# Share Wi-Fi internet connection through hotspot

Tags: wireless, internet

I was trying to share internet to my mobile phone using hotspot, but the problem is that I can't connect and share internet connection using the same driver.

I used to do these procedures easily on Windows. Is there an equivalent role in Ubuntu?

Comment: that is, your computer is connected to internet using wifi and you want to share this connection using the same wifi card?

Comment: yes, is there's any way to do such thing